# How to pass query string data or any value from url to controller function in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Suppose I have few links in page and each link has date like:

```
**https://mysite/blogs/01/01/2017
https://mysite/blogs/02/01/2017
https://mysite/blogs/03/01/2017
https://mysite/blogs/04/01/2017**
```

How can I capture date and fetch data date wise when doing Angular routing ?

I am new so like to know how people pass query string data or any value from url to controller function with example code.

```
**https://mysite/blogs?custid=101&orderid=200
https://mysite/blogs/{customerid}/orders
https://mysite/blogs/{customerid}/{orderid}**
```

Please post a small sample code having controller, view and routing code if possible.

I am very eager to see how to handle query string or rest based URL kind with Angular routing which will pass data to controller and  controller fetch data accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$routeProvider.when('/blogs/:day/:month/:year', {
    templateUrl: 'blog.html',
    controller: 'BlogCtrl'
});
```

Then in your controller, inject [`$routeParams`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/$routeParams) to get the params:

```
function BlogCtrl($scope, $routeParams) {
    $scope.day = $routeParams.day;
    $scope.month = $routeParams.month;
    $scope.year = $routeParams.year;
}
```

### [Demo JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Mistalis/1dr14c34/)

Comment: perfect example but why you use :day or :month ? why :with variable name ? is it any kind of convention in angular ?

Comment: please show me how to work with multiple query string. just edit your example a bit if possible. thanks

Comment: `:` means it is a **variable**: it will match anything, and will be added to the [`$routeParams`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/$routeParams) service.

Comment: i just bit modify your code for working with 2 query string but code now not working. here is jsfiddle link http://jsfiddle.net/tridip/1dr14c34/1/  please see the link and tell me where i made the mistake.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `$location` object. Here's a link to the [official documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/$location)

And here's a sample of code using it :

```
if ($location.hash() !== "") {
  $scope.date = $location.hash();
  $scope.loadData();
} else $scope.initWithDefaultValues();
```

But your url list should look like this :

```
**https://mysite/blogs#01/01/2017
https://mysite/blogs#02/01/2017
https://mysite/blogs#03/01/2017
https://mysite/blogs#04/01/2017**
```

Once you did this, you can also set your browser url this way :

```
$location.hash( myUrlList[foo].split("#")[1] );
```

Where myUrlList contains your url list as shown upper.

In order this solution to work, you'll have to declare $http, $location, and perhaps also $anchorScroll depending of what you're doing with your date.

Comment: can you please dump and run your code in jsfiddle and get me that working version link ?

Comment: what is the meaning of this line $location.hash( myUrlList[foo].split("#")[1] ); ?

Comment: this means that you get the url in `myUrlList` at the index `foo` (`myUrlList[foo]`). Then, you keep only the part of the url after the # (`.split("#")[1]`). Finally, you put the result in the hash of your url (the part after the #), invoking the `$location.hash` method.

Answer (score 0):

This means that in all other cases that those mentionned in when clauses, the route is redirected to '/'. This solution shows how to use a different controller and route depending on the original url.